# What does the registerChangeListener method do in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-11

I recently started working with JavaFX. I changed the JDK from 8 to 11 in my project and there is a class that uses this method:

```
public class LabeledColorPickerSkin extends ColorPickerSkin {
    public LabeledColorPickerSkin(final LabeledColorPicker colorPicker) {
        super(colorPicker);
        registerChangeListener(colorPicker.valueProperty(), "VALUE");
        text.setText(colorPicker.text);
        updateColor();
     }
}
```

It is used here:

```
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;

public class LabeledColorPicker extends ColorPicker {
    public LabeledColorPicker()
    {
        super();
        getStyleClass().addAll("labeled-color-picker",
                "text-visible");
    }
    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new LabeledColorPickerSkin(this);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    String text;
}
```

In version 8 the method looked like this:

```
protected final void registerChangeListener(ObservableValue<?> property, String reference) {
    if (changeListenerHandler == null) {
        changeListenerHandler = new MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler(p -> {
            handleControlPropertyChanged(p);
            return null;
        });
    }
    changeListenerHandler.registerChangeListener(property, reference);
}
```

And now it looks like this:

```
protected final void registerChangeListener(ObservableValue<?> property, Consumer<ObservableValue<?>> consumer) {
    if (lambdaChangeListenerHandler == null) {
        lambdaChangeListenerHandler = new LambdaMultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler();
    }
    lambdaChangeListenerHandler.registerChangeListener(property, consumer);
}
```

I do not understand what this method does and how to rewrite this code for JavaFX 11.

Comment: Which code do you want to rewrite? I can't see in your posted question the usage of the old signature. In the old API you could pas a descriptive string of the property and use that to know what had changed and re-query it. In the new code you can pass a lambda handler getting the observable value directly.

Comment: I want to rewrite this public class LabeledColorPickerSkin extends ColorPickerSkin {
public LabeledColorPickerSkin(final LabeledColorPicker colorPicker) {
    super(colorPicker);
    registerChangeListener(colorPicker.valueProperty(), "VALUE");
    text.setText(colorPicker.text);
    updateColor();
 }
}

Comment: please do not clarify details of your quesiton as comments, instead edit the question and add them there

Comment: a good general approach to solving questions like this is to read the code in the core skins: compare what they did before going public (fx8) and after (fx9+) - they did exactly what you need and as such are good blueprints :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is used for registering listeners to properties of the control. It makes sure only a single listener is used for this purpose in addition to making sure a `WeakChangeListener` is used to allow the skin to be garbage collected, if you replace it.

In JavaFX 8 the containing class `SkinBase` (as well as subclasses like `ColorPickerSkin`) was part of the internal API and used `String`s to be notified of changes of properties (yikes). When a property was changed, the `handleControlPropertyChanged` method was called receiving with the string passed to as second argument to the `registerChangeListener` method as parameter.

The following code is from the source code of `ColorPickerSkin`, but the code you're working with should contain something similar:

```
@Override protected void handleControlPropertyChanged(String p) {
    super.handleControlPropertyChanged(p);

    if ("SHOWING".equals(p)) {
        ...
    } else if ("VALUE".equals(p)) {
        /* Some logic for updating the GUI */
    }
}
```

To rewrite the code for the new (JavaFX 9+) API you need move the logic executed, if `"VALUE"` is passed as parameter to the method from this method to a `Consumer<ObservableValue<?>>`:

```
public LabeledColorPickerSkin(final LabeledColorPicker colorPicker) {
    super(colorPicker);
    registerChangeListener(colorPicker.valueProperty(), observable -> {
        /* Some logic for updating the GUI */
    });
    text.setText(colorPicker.text);
    updateColor();
}
```

Comment: hmm... _single listener_ could be a bit confusing: indeed it's a single one at the property, but that's a chain of as many as are registered :)